# program to evaluate the polynomial ax 3 + bx 2 + cx + d with minimum number of operations for given values of a,b,c and d

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

Please suggest subroutine program to evaluate the polynomial  ax 3 + bx 2 + cx + d with minimum number of operations for given values of  a,b,c and d.

If using bisection method is there any way to guess limit values dynamically.

Comment: In order to get good responses, here are a few things to keep in mind. 1) Assume you'll need to write all the code yourself. We'll generally only point you in the right direction. 2) What Have You Tried? (Google that phrase). We need to see your attempts at solving this. 3) Make sure you've thoroughly checked documentation and a search engine. If someone else finds the answer that way, you'll get a curt "RTD" or "LMGTFY" and a LOT of downvotes.

Comment: What do bisection and limit values have to do with polynomial evaluation?

Comment: What I found on web is bisection method to solve polynomial equation if limits(upper and lower) are guessed, but not sure that implies to minimum number of operations or not.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method to evaluate `f(x)=ax³+bx²+cx+d` is the Horner scheme which uses parantheses to transform the expression to

```
f(x) = ((a*x+b)*x+c)*x+d
```

---

For finding roots note that at `x=-R` and `x=+R` where

```
R = 1+max(abs(b), abs(c), abs(d))/abs(a)
```

the polynomial will have non-zero values of opposite sign. Use bisection or better regula-falsi with the Illinois-anti-stalling modification.